# use xslt to concat repeating child nodes into one line of csv/ tsv

Tags: python, xml, xslt

if I have the following xml file

```
<AnnotationSet Name="Bio">
<Annotation Id="6164" Type="Health_Care_Related_Organization" StartNode="0" EndNode="6">
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">VOCABS</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">NCI</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">Negation</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">Affirmed</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">inst_full</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/umls/id/C0002424</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">Experiencer</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">Patient</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">PREF</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">Clinic</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">inst</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">C0002424</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">STY</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">Health Care Related Organization</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">TUI</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">T093</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">language</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String"></Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">Temporality</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">Recent</Value>
</Feature>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">tui_full</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/semanticnetwork/id/T093</Value>
</Feature>
</Annotation>
</AnnotationSet>
```

I would like to be able to take the `Name` element of each child node `<Feature>` and a column header, and the `<Value>` element as a value and put into a csv or tsv. I would also like `StartNode` and `EndNode` as columns from the `<Annotation>` node.

It would look something like:

```
StartNode    EndNode    VOCABS    Negation    ....
---------    -------    ------    --------    ----
0            6          NCI       Affirmed    ....
```

I am only familiar with writing XSLT where each node i.e. `<Feature>` contains every column for each row. Here, each row is contained within `<Annotation>` and am having difficulty pulling out what I need.

I tried writing the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Name, Value &#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="AnnotationSet/Annotation/Feature">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name,',',Value)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but cannot get this to run when testing on http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Anyone have any ideas?

I would ideally like to do this in python once the xslt is tested, where I have the following python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import lxml.etree as ET
import sys
import os

dom = ET.parse('gatetest.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('gate.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: Show the XSLT you are currently using

Comment: sorry thought i had put in - will correct

Comment: just forget the code tags. sorry!

Comment: You are trying to use XSLT in an imperative manner, when it is not really an imperative language.  Read up on `apply-templates` and the [push vs pull](http://www.eddiewelker.com/2008/11/25/push-style-xslt-vs-pull-style/) style of writing XSLT.  Learn to use XSLT the way it was intended to work.

Comment: @brucezepplin Will there always be only one `Annotation` element in the input - hence one data row in the output?

Comment: @michael, not there will be multiple

Comment: @michael - there will be multiple `Annotation` elements, where each one equates to one row of data, but I can assure you that the sub elements of each `Annotation` element are structured exactly the same, where only the `Value` attrib changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to concatenate `Name` and `Value` makes no sense, because you need them one below the other, not one besides the other. Not to mention that you need each name only once (in the top row).

Try it this way instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/AnnotationSet">
    <xsl:text>StartNode&#9;EndNode</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Annotation[1]/Feature">
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="Annotation">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@StartNode" />
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@EndNode" />
        <xsl:for-each select="Feature">
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result in your example will look something like this (it's difficult to show tab-separated values correctly aligned):

```
StartNode   EndNode VOCABS  Negation    inst_full   Experiencer PREF    inst    STY TUI language    Temporality tui_full
0   6   NCI Affirmed    http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/umls/id/C0002424 Patient Clinic  C0002424    Health Care Related Organization    T093        Recent  http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/semanticnetwork/id/T093
```